Conway Game of Life Growth Rate
I am looking at https://conwaylife.com/wiki/Infinite_growth#cite_note-6. The slowest growth rate is obviously $0$ and the largest growth rate is obviously $O(n^2)$. It seems that the middle is well-filled. So I am kind of wondering:
Given a function $f: \mathbb{N} \to [0,\infty)$, $f(n) \leqslant n^2$, $f(n) \to \infty$ monotonically as $n \to \infty$, is there always a starting pattern in Conway's game of life such that its growth rate is in $\Theta(f)$ ?

Doesn't the linked page answer your question as to what is known about that question?

The page says quite a bunch of growth rates are possible. But not all of them.

The page says “this is everything that's known”. I doubt readers of this stack exchange are going to know more.

Ah. I see what you mean. Just treat this as a fun open problem then...

@RobPratt  I removed the [tag:game-of-life] tag because no such tag currently exists on Math SE, and the community has a process for creating new tags ( https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35451/ ).  The ad hoc creation of new tags, without prior discussion, is discouraged.  In this case, the [tag:cellular-automata] tag seems to get the job done.
